# Maximum likelihood with order statistics in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm testing the Maximum Likelihood method, when only the maximum value of a sample is provided. I'm assuming the sample is from a Gaussian Distribution.

First I generate 10.000 random number with mean = 2.45 & sd = 1

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(91)
n <- 10000
mean <- 2.45
sd <- 1
random_numbers <- rnorm(n, mean, sd)
```

Then I extract the max value, and I assume that's the only value I know.

```
maximum <- random_numbers[which.max(random_numbers)]
```

Then, I estimate the density value for that maximum value using different mean values. I use the formula:

[image: formula]

```
mean_space <- seq(0, 10, by = 0.01)
densities <- n * (pnorm(maximum, mean_space, sd)^(n-1)) * dnorm(maximum,
  mean_space,1)

df <- data.frame(x = mean_space, y = densities)
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
 geom_line() +
 geom_vline(xintercept = mean)
print(g)
df %>% filter(y == max(y))
```

However, I'm getting density values higher than 1 which I think are not correct.

Comment: Density values greater than 1 aren't necessarily a problem (see `curve(dnorm(x, sd=.1), from=-2, to=2)` - that curve goes over 1). It's just that the sum of the area under the density needs to be 1. But this seems more like a question about statistical theory which might be better asked at [stats.se].

Comment: Thanks for the example. I wasn't sure where to ask. I'll try Cross Validated.